# tess4j OCRtest JBoss ERROR java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, jboss, ocr, slf4j, tess4j

I can't use the tess4j OCR library with my JBoss 7.1.1. I haven't a Maven configuration and no idea about the exception. I think is a conflict problem with the slf4j logging library.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String filein = getServletContext().getRealPath("/test/img/pic.png");
    File imageFile = new File(filein);
    ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();

    try{
        String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
        System.out.println(result);
    }catch (TesseractException e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].(...)facade.reports.OCRtest]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet.service() para servlet (...)facade.reports.OCRtest lanzó excepción: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger()V
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoggerConfig.loadConfig(Unknown Source) [tess4j-3.3.0.jar:]
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoggHelper.toString(Unknown Source) [tess4j-3.3.0.jar:]
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.<clinit>(Unknown Source) [tess4j-3.3.0.jar:]
at (...)facade.reports.OCRtest.doGet(OCRtest.java:36) [classes:]
```

Comment: Did you include [`jul-to-slf4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j/3.3.0) JAR?

Comment: Yes of course and some libraries from tess4j folder.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem once while implementing OCR with tess4j. I did a lot of research to solve my issue by breaking my head with the slf4j legacy implementation and re-configuring the log4j properties used in my maven project.

And one fine day, I read in their offical page about removing the line which was causing the problem, i.e `removeHandlersForRootLogger();` and then I did remove this line from the `loadderConfig.java` util file and **Eureka!! it started working.**

Follow these steps :

1. Download the whole project from the [offical site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tess4j/).
2. Find your way to the `tess4j\util` folder. Mine was like this: `D:\Tess4J\src\net\sourceforge\tess4j\util`. Then open the `loaderConfig.java` file and remove/comment the `removeHandlersForRootLogger();` line.
3. Later build the whole project again using Ant commands. Since it is an Apache Ant project check out the `build.xml` and explore about building ant projects, it's fun learning new things.

If you didn't get lucky building the project, open **cmd prompt** in the corresponding folder which contains build.xml and type **ant** and press enter, it will start building with the configurations from the build.xml feeds

4. Voilà, you have your own JAR created in the `dist` folder.
5. Now include this JAR into your project repository.